# Can't change permissions of a drive in an external hard disk?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I have to say I have never had problems with changing permissions before this, but I have just freshly installed 18.04 and for whatever reason I can't change my permissions on any file within the drive. I have complete write/read access... so its a baffler for sure.

```
hutber@hutber:/mnt/2tb$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov  6 23:51  ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Nov  5 22:47  ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov  7 00:00 'jamie'/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov  3 00:28 '$RECYCLE.BIN'/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov  2 18:17 'System Volume Information'/
hutber@hutber:/mnt/2tb$ cd ../
hutber@hutber:/mnt$ sudo chown -R hutber:hutber ./2tb/jamie/
hutber@hutber:/mnt/2tb$ ll ./2tb
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov  6 23:51  ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Nov  5 22:47  ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Nov  7 00:00 'jamie'/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov  3 00:28 '$RECYCLE.BIN'/
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov  2 18:17 'System Volume Information'/
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is that its NTFS, so the user that mounts it, is the user that has ownership (because linux permissions don't translate to NTFS)

You can mount it as another user or set the user in fstab if needed to change it to be a set user.

Usually ubuntu will do this automatically when you click on it to mount it (if you have it mounted on start up its going to be root user unless you specify otherwise)

Comment: Humm ok nice, thanks Liz. I need to work out how to mouth it as another use them. I'll google it